# is history.push() an async call in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using history object(passed from component to reducer) provided by react in my reducer to conditionally route to other pages while updating the state.
I knew thats not how navigation must be handled.
But its still working, Is the history.push() function async call as i am 
executing it before returning modified state in reducer.
Can someone explain me why this works

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
var stateClone = {...state};
switch(action.type)
{
  case 'LogIn':
  var user = state.users.filter((user) => user.userName === action.userName && user.password === action.password );
  if(user.length > 0 )
  {
    var loggedInUser = {...user[0]};
    stateClone.loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
    action.history.push('/products');
    return stateClone;
  }
  else {
    alert('Wrong Credentials');
  }
  return state;
}
}
```

Comment: `history.push` may be synchronous but it may affect the app in asynchronous way. A reducer shouldn't contain side effects, for starters.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is an async call. Check out this [discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6512).